# Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am trying to check the version of my app with the iTunes lookup api. I have problems in parsing the response. Please find the code

```
static func needsUpdate() -> Bool
{
    do {
        let infoDictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary
        let appID = infoDictionary?["CFBundleIdentifier"]
        let url:URL = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=\(appID!)")!
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let lookup = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]

        print(lookup)

        let resultCount:Int = lookup["resultCount"] as! Int

        if (resultCount == 1)
        {
            var results = lookup["results"] as! [String:AnyObject]  // ***Error***

            if results.isEmpty
            {
                print(results)
            }
        }

    } catch
    {

    }
    return true
}
```

Please let me know how can i parse this response

Comment: Make a breakpoint to check what's in `lookup`.

Answer (score 15):

The error message clearly reveals that the value for `results` is an **array**.

```
let results = lookup["results"] as! [[String:Any]]
```

And consider that a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` in Swift 3